# Chapter headings too wide for page, but won't break

Tags: line-breaking, chapters

I'm preparing a document (`scrreprt`) which has pretty long chapter titles. Apparently, those are too long: they exceed the right margin by quite a bit, and of course I'm getting `Overfull \hbox` messages. It looks like this:

[image: Chapter heading #1]

[image: Chapter heading #2]

Any ideas on how I could prevent this? I initially thought LaTeX would insert line breaks between *Marketing-* and *Forschung* (and *und* and *Organisationen*), but it won't do that.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\fontseries{eb}\huge}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\usepackage[default,osfigures]{opensans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, headsep=.35in, footskip=0.4in, headheight=2.5cm, footnotesep=1in}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Käuferverhalten und Marketing-Forschung als Gegenstandsbereiche des Marketing}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is that German? Are you using the `babel` package with `german` option?

Comment: Yep, that's German and I'm using `babel` with the `ngerman` option. Hyphenation works fine for the rest of the document...

Comment: You can do it by yourself. Use `\-` to split a word.

Comment: Actually this should not occur with classes from »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)« since all headings are typeset `\raggedright`. And with »[babel](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel)« you may use shorthands and write `Marketing"=Forschung` to allow hyphenation at arbitrary places.

Comment: Neither one seems to work within the `\chapter{}` environment :/

Comment: Then you will have to supplement your question with a *self-contained* and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Just added a minimal example to my question.

Comment: Do you really need `titlesec` You can achieve the same with `\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontseries{eb}\huge}`. However it seems that `titlesec` doesn't use `\raggedright`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using `babel` with the `ngerman` option, you could solve the issue at hand by (i) replacing `Marketing-Forschung` with `Marketing"=Forschung` in the chapter header and (ii) adding `\raggedright` to the second argument of the `\titleformat{chapter}{...}{...}{}` directive:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\fontseries{eb}\huge\raggedright}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
```

These two changes will produce the following chapter header:

[image]

Comment: According to Bringhurst’s recommendation, headings are more peasant set ragged right without hyphenation. May be you shall add something regarding typography in your answer. I do not have Bringhurst at hand so I cannot give further reference tonight.

Comment: @Sveinung - Since there's already a hyphen in the composite noun "Marketing-Forschung", I think it's OK to let a line break happen at that hyphen. I'm also familiar with Bringhurst's recommendation *not* to hyphenate words in sectioning headers. :-) However, given that his book is on English (and, more specifically, North American) rather than on German typographic usage, I'm not sure if this recommendation carries over directly. Notice that by using the directive `\raggedright` in the sectioning headers, no new hyphenation points will be created.

Comment: Yes, of course, I was not clear. This type of compound words are OK to hyphenate in headings also according to Bringhurst. I was referring to in general.